# Creating new header with existing headers in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query where I have to find the first name and the last name of that student whose GPA is above 3.5. This can be done as follows:

```
select first name, last name 
from Students 
where GPA > 3.5;
```

but I am required to create a new header column "name" which combines the first name and last name (with one space between them). How can I create a new header field?

Comment: You just need to create a new column in your query, where the 2 name fields are `CONCATENATE`d, and give that new column an alias. Concatenation works differently depending on which RDBMS you're using. You should be able to find information about both (concatenation and column aliases) in the appropriate RDBMS's documentation.

Comment: Use `concat()`, `||`, `+`, or `&` depending on your database.

Comment: I am using oracle DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples:

```
   USE AdventureWorks2012 
    Select FirstName,LastName,(FirstName+' '+ LastName) As [Name] from Person.Person
```

Or

```
    Select FirstName,LastName,concat(firstname,' ', lastname) as name
    from Person.Person
```

You will Get the Same Results

[image]

so back to your Query

```
    Select first name, last name ,(FirstName+' '+ LastName) As [Name] 
    From Students 
    Where GPA > 3.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat(`first name`, " ", `last name`) as name
from Students 
where GPA > 3.5;
```

or

```
select concat_ws(" ", `first name`, `last name`) as name
from Students 
where GPA > 3.5;
```